# Could not build Objective-C module 'cocoaMQTT'

Tags: ios, swift, mqtt

I am building an app that should connect to my raspberry pi but after installing MQTT via cocoaPods the import CocoaMQTT gives me this error
"Could not build Objective-C module 'CocoaMQTT'"
I've already deleted my derivedData but thats not working either.

how can I fix this?

```
import UIKit
import CocoaMQTT -> Could not build Objective-C module 'CocoaMQTT'

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func test(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message? That doesn’t give us much to work with.

Comment: after some more searching I found out that the header 'CocoaMQTT-Swift.h' couldn't be found. thats all I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i've fixed it by compiling for a lower iOS deployment.